# Meta Box data not saving when updating the post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a meta box, following a tutorial.  I have triple checked the code that it matches that of the tutorial (in which case, the meta box data IS saving), but on mine, it is not saving.  This is my code.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Post Meta Box
Plugin URI: http://acetronaut.com
Description: Demonstrates how to implement a custom posts meta box into 
wordpress
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Acetronaut
Author URI: http://acetronaut.com
License: GPL2
*/

function acetrnt_add_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'acetrnt-admin', plugins_url( 'custom-post-meta-box/css/admin.css' ) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'acetrnt_add_admin_styles' );

function acetrnt_add_meta_box() {   
    add_meta_box(
        'acetrnt_audio',                // The ID for the meta box
        'Add MP3',                      //The title of the meta box
        'acetrnt_display_meta_box',     //The function for rendering the markup
        'post',                         // We'll only be displaying this on post pages
        'side',                         //Where the meta box should appear
        'core'                          // The priority of where the meta box whould be displayed
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'acetrnt_add_meta_box' );

function acetrnt_display_meta_box( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'acetrnt_nonce_field' ); ?>

    <label id="mp3-title" for="mp3-title">Title of MP3</label>
    <input type="text" id="mp3-title" name="mp3-title" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, true ) ); ?>" placeholder="Your Song By Elton John" />

    <label id="mp3-file" for="mp3-file">MP3 File</label>
    <input type="file" id="mp3-file" name="mp3-file" value="" />

    <?php 
}

function acetrnt_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {
    if ( acetrnt_user_can_save( $post_id, 'acetrnt-nonce-field' ) ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['mp3-title'] ) && 0 < count( strlen( trim( $_POST['mp3-title'] ) ) ) ) {
            $mp3_title = $_POST['mp3-title'];
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mp3-title', $mp3_title );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'acetrnt_save_meta_box_data' );

function acetrnt_user_can_save( $post_id, $nonce ) {
    // Is this an autosave?
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    // Is this a revision?
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    // Is the nonce valid?
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ $nonce] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $nonce ], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) );
    // Return true if the user is able to save the file
    return ! ( $is_autosave || $is_revision ) && $is_valid_nonce;
}
?>
```

I am banging my head against the wall as to the culprit.  Is there anything in my code that is wrong?  I have also tried dropping out of php and using regular html code, but that does not work.

Comment: I took the liberty of tidying up the code, it's really hard to read code without indentation... You can troubleshoot what's going on on `save_post` using the following (it breaks the site, remove after testing): `wp_die( sprintf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $_POST, true ) ) );` ---> here the site will stop the save action and will print the contents of **`$_POST`** on your screen. You can use it anywhere to inspect what's happening with some `$variable`.

Comment: Thanks, my indentation never works on here.  Where exactly am I to put this code?  In my functions.php file?  Anywhere?  And this is just to see the contents of $_POST?

Comment: Nooo, use it on your function `acetrnt_save_meta_box_data`, the code stops everything and prints the content of the $_POST variable

Comment: @brasofilo Alright I put it in my acetrnt_save_meta_box_data (on my local version of the website)  When I refresh the edit post page, nothing happens, but if I input into the new meta box again and hit update, the page returns a huge error with all the information you said.  I'm not really sure what to make of it though.  Some related bits are `[meta] => Array
        (
            [335] => Array
                (
                    [key] => meta-text
                    [value] => Hello World!
                )

        )` and maybe `[meta-text] => Hello World!`

Comment: Yes, that code snippet will stop the program right where you put it and show the contents of the variable as an "error".